# why Remote Validation is not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

i tried to to validate my username remotely ,unfortunately is not firing 
here are my codes for viewmodel

```
public class UsersNew
{
public IList<RoleCheckbox> Roles { get; set; }

[Required,StringLength(6,MinimumLength =3)]
[Remote("IsAvailable","Validation")]
[RegularExpression(@"(\S)+",ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
public string username { get; set; }

[Required,DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string password { get; set; }

[Required,MaxLength(256),DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string email { get; set; }
}
```

my controller

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{

public JsonResult IsAvailable(string username)
{
if (!Database.Session.Query<User>().Any(u => u.username == username))
return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 string suggestedUID = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} is 
not available ", username);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
 string altCandidate = username + i.ToString();
 if (!Database.Session.Query<User>().Any(u => u.username == altCandidate))
 {
 suggestedUID = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} is not 
 available. Try {1}", username,
  altCandidate);
 break;
 }

 }
 return Json(suggestedUID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
 }
```

i even include default jquery validation

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In Model on username I have Added Error Message "Username is not available"

```
public class UsersNew
{
    [Required, StringLength(6, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Remote("IsAvailable", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "Username is not available ")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "White space is not allowed.")]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(256), DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller must either Return **"True" of "False"** in Remote Validation.

```
public JsonResult IsAvailable(string username)
{
    if (!Database.Session.Query<User>().Any(u => u.username == username))
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string altCandidate = username + i.ToString();
        if (!Database.Session.Query<User>().Any(u => u.username == altCandidate))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you want to display custom ErrorMessage then Used $Ajax POST Request to POST Username and Get Result and you can display it.

Reference for Remote Validation :- [Remote Validation Sample](http://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/remote-validations-in-asp-net-mvc-4-with-example)

Comment: 1. Remove Layout of page and add Jquery and Css Reference which are required on it.  2.Check in browser Console for Errors.

Comment: i've added all necessary jquery   libs

Comment: n from jquery i get these errors jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function TypeError: $(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a functio

Comment: @Vondella21 Check jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js is added

Comment: i added them by default  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")